# Accessing Grails asset pipeline from Config.groovy

Tags: grails, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I have recently updated my Grails app to 2.4.4 and am now using the asset-pipeline plugin. I am also using the CKEditor text editor plugin.

CKEditor loads its configuration from a Javascript file, ckconfig.js, which I have stored in /assets/javascripts/ckconfig.js. Loading of this file is declared in Config.groovy:

```
// CKeditor basic configuration
ckeditor {
    config = "ckconfig.js"
    skipAllowedItemsCheck = false
    defaultFileBrowser = "ofm"
}
```

Unfortunately, my configuration is not being loaded and I get a Javascript console error "TypeError: d is undefined".

How do I refer to a Javascript file in the asset pipeline from within Config.groovy?

```
config = "assets/javascripts/ckconfig.js"
```

does not work. Is there a fixed path or URL? Or something cleverer?

For reference, I'm using ckeditor 4.4.1.0 plugin and application.js contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom
//= require cinnabar.js
//= require ckeditor/ckeditor
//= require ckconfig.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in same environment:

```
ckeditor {
    config = "/assets/ckconfig.js"
    ...
```

I placed the file in `grails-app\assets\javascripts\ckconfig.js`